# is there a continuous function that satisfies the condition

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have seen the function f(x) is rational when x is rational and f(x) is irrational if x is irrational being continuous. is there a continuous function f:ℝ→ℝ such that f(x) is rational if x is irrational and f(x) is irrational if x is rational ?

Comment: The first example is trivial: $f(x)=x$ satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @Clayton I'm afraid $f(x)=x$ is not rational for irrational $x$...

Comment: @CiaPan: No, but it is rational for rational $x$. And it is irrational for irrational $x$; moreover, it is also continuous...

Comment: @Clayton But Man asked about a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ 'such that f(x) is rational if x is irrational' and vice versa.

Comment: @CiaPan: His first statement is that he has seen continuous $f(x)$ such that it is rational for rational input, irrational for irrational input. He seemed to state it as if it were some pathological function, so I gave an example where it is entirely obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The range of a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ can never be a countably infinite set.

Comment: This is perfect. $+1$

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: @Man: How many different types of cardinalities can you have, keeping in mind this hint?

Comment: @Man $f(\Bbb Q)$ is countable and $f(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\subseteq \Bbb Q$ is countable, hence $f(\Bbb R$) is countable - and contains at least two distict points $a:=f(\sqrt 2)\in \Bbb Q$ and $b:=f(0)\notin \Bbb Q$. By IVT, it must contain the - uncountable - interval $[a,b]$

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. still not able to get it .how is f(Q) countable.

Comment: @Man The set $\mathbb Q$ is countable, so $f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb Q$ can have at most that many values, hence $f(\mathbb Q)$ is at most countably infinte.

Comment: @Man $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is countable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is: If we enumerate the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\{q_1,q_2,\cdots\}$ then we also have an enumeration $\{f(q_1),f(q_2),\cdots\}$ of $f(\mathbb{Q})$. It is also important to note that the argument only works for $\textbf{non-constant}$ continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (which is indeed required).

Comment: got it .how is f(R) countable when R is not countable then.

Comment: Well, there are only countably many rationals ...